# Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I get the following error :

```
org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
```

I get this error even though I'm developing a Spring boot project. I thought that the cfg.xml isn't needed in Spring boot and is instead replaced with the application.properties file which content is:

```
# Update tables
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@asdsfdorasfc2.asdssf.ca:1521:dbmas
spring.datasource.username=userkoas
spring.datasource.password=dsgfsgfdgfdg454g5#2f#$@
spring.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.dbcp.maxTotal=1
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=1
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

# Logging
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

# Views
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

This error comes up when I call my controller that calls a HQL Query :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/film/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String read(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model) {
        Film film = filmService.getFilm(Long.parseLong(id));

        // Get Genres
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        String query = "FROM Pays WHERE idfilm = " + id;

        List genres = (List) session.createQuery(query).list();

        System.out.println(genres);

        session.flush();
        session.close();

        model.addAttribute("film", film);
        return "film";
    }
```

My SessionFactory Singleton :

```
public class Util {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed. " + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't please don't... Ditch the `HibernateUtil` and let Spring Boot create the `Entitymangaer` for you. You are working around Spring Boot and the auto configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum Quick reply lol, I'll check that out thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that the cfg.xml isn't needed in Spring boot and is instead replaced with the `application.properties` file which content is:

It isn't if you would actually **use** Spring Boot. But the fact that you are using a `HibernateUtil` means you are working around Spring Boot and its auto configuration. So in short ditch the `HibernateUtil` you are using and instead use JPA instead of plain Hibernate.

The code you wrote belongs in a repository or service instead of in the controller and instead of the `SessionFactory` inject the transactional `EntityManager` instead.

```
public class GenreRepository {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @Transactional
  public List<Genre> findForMovie(Movie movie) {
    String query = "FROM Pays WHERE idfilm = :id";
    return em.createQuery(query, Genre.class).setParameter("id", movie.getId() ).getResultList();
  }
}
```

Which is all you need. Spring Boot will auto configure the JPA part, datasource etc. The same thing you should probably be doing for your `FilmService` as well.